# I want to pass a widget which also pass a String value in a void method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Error: The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(String)'.

```
void _showTicketDetails(Widget
      parentTicketDetailsTitle(String parentTicketInfo), Widget parentTicketDetailsContent()) {
    //Flutter defined function showDialog();
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          titlePadding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          title: parentTicketDetailsTitle(parentTicketInfo),
          content: parentTicketDetailsContent(),
        );
      },
    );
  }



Widget _ticketDetails7Title(String ticketInfo) {
    return Column(...
    );
  }

Widget _createTicketDetailsContent() {
    return Container(...
    );
  }

GestureDetector(
                                                        onTap: () =>
                                                            _showTicketDetails(
                                                                _ticketDetails7Title('Create Ticket'),
                                                                _createTicketDetailsContent),
),
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your question with guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<Widget> _showTicketDetails(
  String parentTicketInfo,
  Widget parentTicketDetailsTitle(String parentTicketInfo),
  Widget parentTicketDetailsContent()) async {
//Flutter defined function showDialog();
return await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      titlePadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      title: parentTicketDetailsTitle(parentTicketInfo),
      content: parentTicketDetailsContent(),
       actions: [
         FlatButton(
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
           },
           child: Text('Close'),
         ),
       ],
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: The problem is solved by replacing my void method with the Future method and placing async and await in the right place. I have also another problem with passing the Widget parameter which also passing a String parameter, and I've solved the problem by defining the String parameter first and then passing it into the Widget parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
void _showTicketDetails(Widget
  parentTicketDetailsTitle, Widget parentTicketDetailsContent()) {
    //Flutter defined function showDialog();
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          titlePadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          contentPadding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
          actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          title: parentTicketDetailsTitle,
          content: parentTicketDetailsContent(),
        );
      },
    );
  }



  Widget _ticketDetails7Title(String ticketInfo) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(ticketInfo),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _createTicketDetailsContent() {
    return Container(
      child: Text('hello'),
    );
  }
  gesture()
  {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>
          _showTicketDetails(
              _ticketDetails7Title('Create Ticket'),
              _createTicketDetailsContent),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you found it helpful then pls upvote or accept the answer it motivates us to help you out. You can accept by checking the tick option or upvote by pressing the up arrow on top left of my answer.